# How to write a condition tag for service search

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer

I am using WIX to create MSI installers for C# services. The MSI does 3 jobs :

a) Copy solution file from bin to a particular location.

b) Create a folder where the service writes it's logs.

c) install the service on the machine if it previously does not exist.

I want to write a condition to check if the service has already been installed on the machine.

This is the registry search :

```
<Property Id="MYSERVICE">
  <RegistrySearch Id="SERVICE_CHECK" Root="HKLM" Name="Install" Type="raw" Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Service"/>
</Property>
```

This is the code for installing the service using custom action:

```
<Condition Message="service der already"><![CDATA[Installed OR (MYSERVICE <> Null)]]></Condition>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='CMDInstallService' Before='InstallFinalize'></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

How do I write the condition, which will check that is the service exists then do nothing, else install the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is this, the issue was with the syntax.

The syntax should have been

NOT SERVICE was the golden answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given the service is part of the product assigning it to its own feature will handle this.

Comment: Upgrade element will check the version of the product installed, but here i am trying to install a service as part of the product(i.e the MSI file) installation.

Comment: Updated answer per your comment, a suggestion perhaps to note that the service is just one part of your installer, or rather your installer is doing more than just installing the service would be a helpful edit for your post so that others don't make the same mistake I did.

Comment: I got it. 

The syntax should have been <Condition Message="service der already"><![CDATA[NOT MYSERVICE]]></Condition>

Comment: If you change your comment to an answer I'll remove my answer. Glad you figured out your issue.